# Facebook - using FBJS to generate flash dynamically?

Tags: flash, facebook, fbml, fbjs

I have tried using the FBML to display the flash statically.  it is simple.

and I have used the FBJS to dynamically display normal content.

So, how to use FBJS to create the tag for displaying Flash?

I have tried setInnerXHTML but doesn't seems working.   So, how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good article which explains how to use Flash in FB.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/facebook/articles/flash_on_facebook.html